# tracemalloc.get_traced_memory shows about 1/10 of memory usage compared with `top`

Tags: python, profiling, memory-profiling

I use `tracemalloc` in the `main` function to measure a Python3 program that is heavily using `threading`. I periodically get two stats from the main function

1. Take a `tracemalloc.take_snapshot()` and then add all `size` of the files from `Snapshot.statistics('filename')`
2. Also call the `tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()` to get the current size and peak size of memory blocks.

The result at the first step roughly matches the current size of memory consumption at the second step. However, both of these numbers are only about 1/10 of the memory consumption if I do `top` and check the same running instance.

I fail to find any document that could explain this discrepancy, nor to clarify whether or not `tracemalloc` could use to measure the memory of a thread-based multithreading program.